# Datatable how to pass data from input to controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

In datatable I have for every row one input,and I want to add some text to this input and for every input I want to take the text and save it into database
Im using laravel and want to use ajax
Now its working fine only for the first input but for the second whatever I wrote it will take the first input text

**input field:**

```
{data: 'vendor_id',mRender: function (data, type, row) {                   
    return '<label hidden>'+data+'</label> <input type="text" id="vendor_name" class="vendor_name" data-id="'+row.id+'" onClick="this.select();" value="'+data+'">';}
},

{data: 'vendor_no', mRender: function (data, type, row) {                   
    return '<label hidden>'+data+'</label> <input type="text" id="vendor_no" class="vendor_no"  onClick="this.select();" value="'+data+'">';}
},
```

**ajax sending variable to controller**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('blur focusout', "#vendor_name", function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Vendor_Save',
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'currentid': id,
                'current_vendor_name':$('#vendor_name').val(),
              },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can't repeat ID's in a page...they are unique by definition. Use class instead

Comment: its the same problem please help me

Comment: After you fix class... you need current instance value ... `'current_vendor_name':$(this).val()`

Comment: wow . great thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ID's must be unique...use the class instead and you need the value of the  class instance that the event occurs on.

```
$(document).on('blur focusout', ".vendor_name", function(){
                                // ^^ class selector
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Vendor_Save',
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'currentid': id,
            'current_vendor_name':$(this).val(),// `this` is current instance
          },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: but what if i want to fill the input fields which is in the same row on event blure of different input field?

Comment: store `var $input =$(this)` and in callback `$input.closest('tr').find('.someOtherInputClass').val(someVarFromResponse)`

Comment: actually I want to show different data in other field has the class .vendor_no and this will be inside  success: function(data) {}

Comment: well you traverse to the row the same way and also use find() the same way then do whatever method you need

Comment: thank you very much and sorry for buthering you but what do you mean by storing $(this) in input variable?

Comment: just final question please, I have in the same row input field called vendor_no and I want to store any text on it in the blur function of what you answered, I can't understand what  var $input =$(this)  means
Im sorry Im begginer

Comment: Before `$.ajax` ... `var $row = $(this).closest('tr')` ... inside the success callback `this` is something different but you can do `$row.find('.someClass').doSomething()`